# How to set custom stroke color when using svg background-image

Tags: html, css

I'm css beginner.

I'm struggling the last few hours in creating a toggle switch to toggle dark mode with an icon representing the current mode. Fortunately, I managed to have different icon depending whether the checkbox is checked or not.

Now, what left is set icon stroke to color var that differ depending on the current theme (light/dark).

I've created a codepen https://codepen.io/jam2020/pen/ExEozxw?editors=1100, and I set the background color of inner circle to red to make it little bit obvious

```css
:root {
  --n: gray;
  --s: white;
  --b1: black;
  --b3: red;
  --tt-width: 40px;
  --tt-height: 22px;
  --tt-border-radius: 11px;
  --tt-circle-size: calc(var(--tt-height) - 4px);
  --tt-icon-size: calc(var(--tt-circle-size) - 2px);
  --tt-light-icon: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg class="ThemeTogglerIcon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M12,18c-3.3,0-6-2.7-6-6s2.7-6,6-6s6,2.7,6,6S15.3,18,12,18zM12,8c-2.2,0-4,1.8-4,4c0,2.2,1.8,4,4,4c2.2,0,4-1.8,4-4C16,9.8,14.2,8,12,8z" /><path d="M12,4c-0.6,0-1-0.4-1-1V1c0-0.6,0.4-1,1-1s1,0.4,1,1v2C13,3.6,12.6,4,12,4z" /><path d="M12,24c-0.6,0-1-0.4-1-1v-2c0-0.6,0.4-1,1-1s1,0.4,1,1v2C13,23.6,12.6,24,12,24z" /><path d="M5.6,6.6c-0.3,0-0.5-0.1-0.7-0.3L3.5,4.9c-0.4-0.4-0.4-1,0-1.4s1-0.4,1.4,0l1.4,1.4c0.4,0.4,0.4,1,0,1.4C6.2,6.5,5.9,6.6,5.6,6.6z" /><path d="M19.8,20.8c-0.3,0-0.5-0.1-0.7-0.3l-1.4-1.4c-0.4-0.4-0.4-1,0-1.4s1-0.4,1.4,0l1.4,1.4c0.4,0.4,0.4,1,0,1.4C20.3,20.7,20,20.8,19.8,20.8z" /><path d="M3,13H1c-0.6,0-1-0.4-1-1s0.4-1,1-1h2c0.6,0,1,0.4,1,1S3.6,13,3,13z" /><path d="M23,13h-2c-0.6,0-1-0.4-1-1s0.4-1,1-1h2c0.6,0,1,0.4,1,1S23.6,13,23,13z" /><path d="M4.2,20.8c-0.3,0-0.5-0.1-0.7-0.3c-0.4-0.4-0.4-1,0-1.4l1.4-1.4c0.4-0.4,1-0.4,1.4,0s0.4,1,0,1.4l-1.4,1.4C4.7,20.7,4.5,20.8,4.2,20.8z" /><path d="M18.4,6.6c-0.3,0-0.5-0.1-0.7-0.3c-0.4-0.4-0.4-1,0-1.4l1.4-1.4c0.4-0.4,1-0.4,1.4,0s0.4,1,0,1.4l-1.4,1.4C18.9,6.5,18.6,6.6,18.4,6.6z" /></svg>');
  --tt-dark-icon: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8, <svg class="ThemeTogglerIcon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M12.1,22c-0.3,0-0.6,0-0.9,0c-5.5-0.5-9.5-5.4-9-10.9c0.4-4.8,4.2-8.6,9-9c0.4,0,0.8,0.2,1,0.5c0.2,0.3,0.2,0.8-0.1,1.1c-2,2.7-1.4,6.4,1.3,8.4c2.1,1.6,5,1.6,7.1,0c0.3-0.2,0.7-0.3,1.1-0.1c0.3,0.2,0.5,0.6,0.5,1c-0.2,2.7-1.5,5.1-3.6,6.8C16.6,21.2,14.4,22,12.1,22zM9.3,4.4c-2.9,1-5,3.6-5.2,6.8c-0.4,4.4,2.8,8.3,7.2,8.7c2.1,0.2,4.2-0.4,5.8-1.8c1.1-0.9,1.9-2.1,2.4-3.4c-2.5,0.9-5.3,0.5-7.5-1.1C9.2,11.4,8.1,7.7,9.3,4.4z" /></svg>');
}

.ThemeToggler {
  width: var(--tt-width);
  height: var(--tt-height);
  flex-shrink: 0;
  border-radius: var(--tt-border-radius);
  background-color: var(--n);
  border: 1px solid var(--b1);
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.ThemeToggler:hover {
  border-color: hsl(var(--s));
}

.ThemeTogglerInput {
  display: none;
}

.ThemeTogglerFill {
  position: relative;
}

.ThemeTogglerFill::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 1px;
  left: 1px;
  height: var(--tt-circle-size);
  width: var(--tt-circle-size);
  background: var(--b3);
  box-shadow: 1px 0px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  border-radius: var(--tt-border-radius);
  /* icon Configuration */
  background-image: var(--tt-light-icon);
  background-size: auto var(--tt-icon-size);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  color: red;
  transition: background-color 0.25s, transform 0.25s;
}

.ThemeTogglerInput:checked~.ThemeTogglerFill::before {
  transform: translateX(var(--tt-circle-size));
  background-image: var(--tt-dark-icon);
}
```

```html
<label class="ThemeToggler" for="ThemeTogglerID">
  <input
    id="ThemeTogglerID"
    class="ThemeTogglerInput"
    type="checkbox"
  />
  <div class="ThemeTogglerFill" >
  </div>
</label>
```

My question now is How I can to set custom stroke color when using svg background-image?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Since the svg's are background-images you can only really edit the svg-code to change the stroke.

If you want to control the color purely by css you would need to embed your svg directly into your hmtl code. Then you could stlye it like any other html-element

Here an example of the direct svg-edit with the color yellow on the moon-icon:

```css
:root {
  --n: gray;
  --s: white;
  --b1: black;
  --b3: red;
  --tt-width: 40px;
  --tt-height: 22px;
  --tt-border-radius: 11px;
  --tt-circle-size: calc(var(--tt-height) - 4px);
  --tt-icon-size: calc(var(--tt-circle-size) - 2px);
  --tt-light-icon: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg class="ThemeTogglerIcon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M12,18c-3.3,0-6-2.7-6-6s2.7-6,6-6s6,2.7,6,6S15.3,18,12,18zM12,8c-2.2,0-4,1.8-4,4c0,2.2,1.8,4,4,4c2.2,0,4-1.8,4-4C16,9.8,14.2,8,12,8z" /><path d="M12,4c-0.6,0-1-0.4-1-1V1c0-0.6,0.4-1,1-1s1,0.4,1,1v2C13,3.6,12.6,4,12,4z" /><path d="M12,24c-0.6,0-1-0.4-1-1v-2c0-0.6,0.4-1,1-1s1,0.4,1,1v2C13,23.6,12.6,24,12,24z" /><path d="M5.6,6.6c-0.3,0-0.5-0.1-0.7-0.3L3.5,4.9c-0.4-0.4-0.4-1,0-1.4s1-0.4,1.4,0l1.4,1.4c0.4,0.4,0.4,1,0,1.4C6.2,6.5,5.9,6.6,5.6,6.6z" /><path d="M19.8,20.8c-0.3,0-0.5-0.1-0.7-0.3l-1.4-1.4c-0.4-0.4-0.4-1,0-1.4s1-0.4,1.4,0l1.4,1.4c0.4,0.4,0.4,1,0,1.4C20.3,20.7,20,20.8,19.8,20.8z" /><path d="M3,13H1c-0.6,0-1-0.4-1-1s0.4-1,1-1h2c0.6,0,1,0.4,1,1S3.6,13,3,13z" /><path d="M23,13h-2c-0.6,0-1-0.4-1-1s0.4-1,1-1h2c0.6,0,1,0.4,1,1S23.6,13,23,13z" /><path d="M4.2,20.8c-0.3,0-0.5-0.1-0.7-0.3c-0.4-0.4-0.4-1,0-1.4l1.4-1.4c0.4-0.4,1-0.4,1.4,0s0.4,1,0,1.4l-1.4,1.4C4.7,20.7,4.5,20.8,4.2,20.8z" /><path d="M18.4,6.6c-0.3,0-0.5-0.1-0.7-0.3c-0.4-0.4-0.4-1,0-1.4l1.4-1.4c0.4-0.4,1-0.4,1.4,0s0.4,1,0,1.4l-1.4,1.4C18.9,6.5,18.6,6.6,18.4,6.6z" /></svg>');
  --tt-dark-icon: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8, <svg class="ThemeTogglerIcon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path fill="yellow" stroke="yellow" d="M12.1,22c-0.3,0-0.6,0-0.9,0c-5.5-0.5-9.5-5.4-9-10.9c0.4-4.8,4.2-8.6,9-9c0.4,0,0.8,0.2,1,0.5c0.2,0.3,0.2,0.8-0.1,1.1c-2,2.7-1.4,6.4,1.3,8.4c2.1,1.6,5,1.6,7.1,0c0.3-0.2,0.7-0.3,1.1-0.1c0.3,0.2,0.5,0.6,0.5,1c-0.2,2.7-1.5,5.1-3.6,6.8C16.6,21.2,14.4,22,12.1,22zM9.3,4.4c-2.9,1-5,3.6-5.2,6.8c-0.4,4.4,2.8,8.3,7.2,8.7c2.1,0.2,4.2-0.4,5.8-1.8c1.1-0.9,1.9-2.1,2.4-3.4c-2.5,0.9-5.3,0.5-7.5-1.1C9.2,11.4,8.1,7.7,9.3,4.4z" /></svg>');
}

.ThemeToggler {
  width: var(--tt-width);
  height: var(--tt-height);
  flex-shrink: 0;
  border-radius: var(--tt-border-radius);
  background-color: var(--n);
  border: 1px solid var(--b1);
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.ThemeToggler:hover {
  border-color: hsl(var(--s));
}

.ThemeTogglerInput {
  display: none;
}

.ThemeTogglerFill {
  position: relative;
}

.ThemeTogglerFill::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 1px;
  left: 1px;
  height: var(--tt-circle-size);
  width: var(--tt-circle-size);
  background: var(--b3);
  box-shadow: 1px 0px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  border-radius: var(--tt-border-radius);
  /* icon Configuration */
  background-image: var(--tt-light-icon);
  background-size: auto var(--tt-icon-size);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  color: red;
  transition: background-color 0.25s, transform 0.25s;
}

.ThemeTogglerInput:checked~.ThemeTogglerFill::before {
  transform: translateX(var(--tt-circle-size));
  background-image: var(--tt-dark-icon);
}
```

```html
<label class="ThemeToggler" for="ThemeTogglerID">
  <input
    id="ThemeTogglerID"
    class="ThemeTogglerInput"
    type="checkbox"
  />
  <div class="ThemeTogglerFill" >
  </div>
</label>
```

Comment: The issue is I need to bind the icon to color var. hmmm, if embedding is my only option. I'm thinking of creating a new class for each icon and modify the there opacity or perhaps display none, but how would I correctly align them to be center the toggle. 

Thanks Christoph