# CSS hide/react multiple dev element on checked

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass, node-sass

I have a toggle switch through using input and hiding the checkbox. However, I couldn't hide a div element with svg as it's content, also tried appending the class to name to the svg it self but nothing happened.

Basically I'm trying to have an icon in the toggle switch that changes depending on on checkbox status. I tried doing it all in css here [How to set custom stroke color when using svg background-image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73195524/how-to-set-custom-stroke-color-when-using-svg-background-image) but I couldn't change the stroke so I'm doing that now

https://codepen.io/jam2020/pen/MWVVwvb?editors=1100

Any ideas, Thanks

```css
$width: 80px;
$height: 44px;
$border-radius: 50px;
$circle-size: $height - 4px;
$icon-size: $circle-size - 2px;
$neutral: red;
$secondary: white;
$base-100: white;
$base-200: gray;
$base-300: black;
$base-content: white;
.ThemeToggler {
  width: $width;
  height: $height;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  border-radius: $border-radius;
  background-color: $neutral;
  border: 1px solid $base-100;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  &:hover {
    border-color: $secondary;
  }
}

.ThemeTogglerFill {
  position: relative;
  &:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 1px;
    left: 1px;
    height: $circle-size;
    width: $circle-size;
    background: $base-300;
    box-shadow: 1px 0px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    border-radius: $border-radius;
    transition: background-color 0.25s, transform 0.25s;
  }
}

.ThemeTogglerInput {
  display: none;
  &:checked~.ThemeTogglerFill::before {
    transform: translateX($circle-size);
  }
  &:checked~.SunIcon {
    display: none;
  }
}

@mixin icon {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: $icon-size;
  height: $icon-size;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  fill: $base-content;
}

.SunIcon {
  @include icon;
  top: 1.8px;
  left: 1.7px;
}

.MoonIcon {
  @include icon;
  top: -35px;
  left: $circle-size + 2px;
}
```

```html
<label class="ThemeToggler" for="ThemeTogglerID">
  <input id="ThemeTogglerID" class="ThemeTogglerInput" type="checkbox" data-toggle-theme="dark,light" data-act-class="ACTIVECLASS" checked />
  <div class="ThemeTogglerFill" >
    <div class="SunIcon">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" >
      <path d="M12,18c-3.3,0-6-2.7-6-6s2.7-6,6-6s6,2.7,6,6S15.3,18,12,18zM12,8c-2.2,0-4,1.8-4,4c0,2.2,1.8,4,4,4c2.2,0,4-1.8,4-4C16,9.8,14.2,8,12,8z" />
      <path d="M12,4c-0.6,0-1-0.4-1-1V1c0-0.6,0.4-1,1-1s1,0.4,1,1v2C13,3.6,12.6,4,12,4z" />
      <path d="M12,24c-0.6,0-1-0.4-1-1v-2c0-0.6,0.4-1,1-1s1,0.4,1,1v2C13,23.6,12.6,24,12,24z" />
      <path d="M5.6,6.6c-0.3,0-0.5-0.1-0.7-0.3L3.5,4.9c-0.4-0.4-0.4-1,0-1.4s1-0.4,1.4,0l1.4,1.4c0.4,0.4,0.4,1,0,1.4C6.2,6.5,5.9,6.6,5.6,6.6z" />
      <path d="M19.8,20.8c-0.3,0-0.5-0.1-0.7-0.3l-1.4-1.4c-0.4-0.4-0.4-1,0-1.4s1-0.4,1.4,0l1.4,1.4c0.4,0.4,0.4,1,0,1.4C20.3,20.7,20,20.8,19.8,20.8z" />
      <path d="M3,13H1c-0.6,0-1-0.4-1-1s0.4-1,1-1h2c0.6,0,1,0.4,1,1S3.6,13,3,13z" />
      <path d="M23,13h-2c-0.6,0-1-0.4-1-1s0.4-1,1-1h2c0.6,0,1,0.4,1,1S23.6,13,23,13z" />
      <path d="M4.2,20.8c-0.3,0-0.5-0.1-0.7-0.3c-0.4-0.4-0.4-1,0-1.4l1.4-1.4c0.4-0.4,1-0.4,1.4,0s0.4,1,0,1.4l-1.4,1.4C4.7,20.7,4.5,20.8,4.2,20.8z" />
      <path d="M18.4,6.6c-0.3,0-0.5-0.1-0.7-0.3c-0.4-0.4-0.4-1,0-1.4l1.4-1.4c0.4-0.4,1-0.4,1.4,0s0.4,1,0,1.4l-1.4,1.4C18.9,6.5,18.6,6.6,18.4,6.6z" />
    </svg>
  </div>
     <div class="MoonIcon">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
      <path d="M12.1,22c-0.3,0-0.6,0-0.9,0c-5.5-0.5-9.5-5.4-9-10.9c0.4-4.8,4.2-8.6,9-9c0.4,0,0.8,0.2,1,0.5c0.2,0.3,0.2,0.8-0.1,1.1c-2,2.7-1.4,6.4,1.3,8.4c2.1,1.6,5,1.6,7.1,0c0.3-0.2,0.7-0.3,1.1-0.1c0.3,0.2,0.5,0.6,0.5,1c-0.2,2.7-1.5,5.1-3.6,6.8C16.6,21.2,14.4,22,12.1,22zM9.3,4.4c-2.9,1-5,3.6-5.2,6.8c-0.4,4.4,2.8,8.3,7.2,8.7c2.1,0.2,4.2-0.4,5.8-1.8c1.1-0.9,1.9-2.1,2.4-3.4c-2.5,0.9-5.3,0.5-7.5-1.1C9.2,11.4,8.1,7.7,9.3,4.4z" />
    </svg>
  </div>
  </div>
</label>
```

Comment: You want to hide one of the icon on toggle right ?

Comment: Do you mean that when the checkbox is checked only the moon should be visible and when the checkbox is un-checked only the sun is visible ?

Comment: Yes, when the icon is checked the moon icon should be visible otherwise the sun icon should be visible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your scss code like this. Make use of visibility property.

```
$width: 80px;
$height: 44px;
$border-radius: 50px;
$circle-size: $height - 4px;
$icon-size: $circle-size - 2px;
$neutral: red;
$secondary: white;
$base-100: white;
$base-200: gray;
$base-300: black;
$base-content: white;

.ThemeToggler {
  width: $width;
  height: $height;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  border-radius: $border-radius;
  background-color: $neutral;
  border: 1px solid $base-100;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  &:hover {
    border-color: $secondary;
  }
}


.ThemeTogglerFill {
  position: relative;
  &:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 1px;
    left: 1px;
    height: $circle-size;
    width: $circle-size;
    background: $base-300;
    box-shadow: 1px 0px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    border-radius: $border-radius;
    transition: background-color 0.25s, transform 0.25s;
  }
}

.ThemeTogglerInput {
  display: none;
  &:checked ~ .ThemeTogglerFill::before {
    transform: translateX($circle-size);
  }
  & + .ThemeTogglerFill{
    .MoonIcon{
      visibility:hidden;
    }
    .SunIcon {
     visibility: visible;
    }
  }
  
  &:checked + .ThemeTogglerFill {
    .SunIcon {
     visibility: hidden;
    }
    .MoonIcon{
      visibility:visible;
    }
  }
}

@mixin icon {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: $icon-size;
  height: $icon-size;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  fill: $base-content;
}

.SunIcon {
  @include icon;
  top: 1.8px;
  left: 1.7px;
}

.MoonIcon {
  @include icon;
  top: -35px;
  left: $circle-size + 2px;
}
```

You can also check the implementation here https://codepen.io/abhay07/pen/QWmmjqq?editors=1100

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate it. I need to play with animation a bit to make it in sync with toggle circle.